# Installing jupyter on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, jupyter

When trying to install jupyter on my Ubuntu 16.04 pc, I get this error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/moeketsi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/moeketsi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/home/moeketsi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
**kwargs
  File "/home/moeketsi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/home/moeketsi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/home/moeketsi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/home/moeketsi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/home/moeketsi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 241, in makedirs
mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ipython_genutils-0.2.0.dist-info'
```

Comment: Be more specific on how are you installing jupyter.

Answer (score 0):

It just looks like you do not have administrator permissions in which case just add the `sudo` prefix.

Also be careful, you might have the wrong installation command.  This looks like it is installing in the integrated Python 3.5 environment in which case if you are not careful you may break your system.